# Error with subdomain basic authentication via htpasswd

Tags: laravel, apache2, .htpasswd

## Issue:

I have Laravel running on Apache 2.4.9 and my domains are organized as follows:

```
beta.domain.com    => /var/www/beta
www.domain.com     => /var/www/live
```

The beta subdomain has basic authentication.  Everything is working as expected except when I started poking around the apache2 error logs.  I get the following error message:

> AH01797: client denied by server configuration:
>   /var/www/beta/public/index.php, referer: https://beta.domain.com/

## My setup:

Here is my setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # Redirect all http traffic to https

    Redirect 301 / https://www.domain.com/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    # some SSL setup for www here

    ServerName www.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/live/public
    <Directory /var/www/live/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>


    LogLevel warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SetEnv ENVIRONMENT "live"

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    # some SSL setup for beta here

    ServerName beta.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/beta/public
    <Directory /var/www/beta/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny

        # allow from one ip
        Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx
        Satisfy any

        AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd/.htpasswd
        AuthName "Password required"
        AuthType Basic
        Require valid-user

    </Directory>


    LogLevel warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SetEnv ENVIRONMENT "beta"

</VirtualHost>
```

## Failed attempts:

I've found several differing answers for this, none of which worked for me.  These are the ones that seem the most convincing, but again they didn't work for me.

1. Replacing `<Directory>` with `<Location>` tags     (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_auth_basic.html#authbasicprovider) - the errors were gone, but I lost basic authentication
2. Using `Require all granted` instead of `Order allow/deny` - this also
       removed basic authentication for me.  Also not sure if this makes
       sense in my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I'm using Apache 2.4+, I changed

```
Order allow, deny
Allow from all
```

to simply

```
Require all granted
```

This fixes the error message, but to allow for basic authentication on the beta subdomain, I also had to remove `Satisfy any`

So the set up for beta would be changed to this:

```
<Directory /var/www/beta/public>

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    # removed in 2.4
    # Order allow,deny

    # allow from one ip
    Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx
    # No longer require Satisfy any in 2.4
    # Satisfy any

    AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd/.htpasswd
    AuthName "Password required"
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user

</Directory>
```